# hylafax + modem (USR Sportster Flash X2) + MODEM TIMEOUT: reading line from modem

Tags: debian, zyxel, fax

I have the following issue with my modem Sportster Flash X2. We had set it up with hylafax and it worked week or two. But today during receiving of fax it hangs and is not responding. Here is log from the last time modem was working

```
<-- [5:ATM0\r]
Oct 14 10:58:36 minos FaxGetty[62820]: --> [2:OK]
Oct 14 11:00:03 minos FaxGetty[62820]: --> [4:RING]
Oct 14 11:00:03 minos FaxGetty[62820]: DynamicConfig: bin/dynconf.php "/dev/ttyS0"
Oct 14 11:00:07 minos FaxGetty[62820]: ANSWER: FAX CONNECTION  DEVICE '/dev/ttyS0'
Oct 14 11:02:01 minos /USR/SBIN/CRON[638]: (logcheck) CMD (   if [ -x /usr/sbin/logcheck ]; then nice -n10 /usr/sbin/logcheck; fi)
Oct 14 11:06:06 minos FaxGetty[62820]: RECV FAX (000000019): from +XX XXX XXXXXX, page 1 in 0:05:59, A4, 3.85 line/mm, 2-D MMR, 14400 bit/s
Oct 14 11:06:06 minos FaxGetty[62820]: RECV FAX (000000019): recvq/fax000000010.tif from +43 316 720883, route to <unspecified>, 1 pages in 0:05:59
Oct 14 11:06:13 minos FaxGetty[62820]: RECV FAX (000000019): session with +XX XXX XXXXXX terminated abnormally: Timeout waiting for Phase C carrier drop
Oct 14 11:06:13 minos FaxGetty[62820]: RECV FAX: bin/faxrcvd.php "recvq/fax000000010.tif" "ttyS0" "000000019" "Timeout waiting for Phase C carrier drop"
Oct 14 11:06:13 minos FaxGetty[62820]: <-- [5:ATH0\r]
Oct 14 11:06:18 minos FaxGetty[62820]: MODEM TIMEOUT: reading line from modem <-- From here modem is not working
```

First we had try to reboot modem because it usually did a magic but it didn't help now. So we also restarted hylafax and even whole server. After hylafax was started again it hangs here

```
Oct 14 11:10:44 minos FaxGetty[62820]: CLOSE /dev/ttyS0
Oct 14 11:10:44 minos FaxQueuer[62798]: MODEM /dev/ttyS0 appears to be wedged
Oct 14 11:10:44 minos FaxQueuer[62798]: MODEM WEDGED: bin/wedged "ttyS0" "/dev/ttyS0"
Oct 14 12:24:59 minos HylaFAX[3772]: HylaFAX INET Protocol Server: restarted.
Oct 14 12:24:59 minos FaxGetty[3790]: OPEN /dev/ttyS0  HylaFAX (tm) Version 6.0.6
Oct 14 12:25:00 minos FaxGetty[3790]: MODEM set DTR OFF
Oct 14 12:25:01 minos FaxGetty[3790]: MODEM set DTR ON
Oct 14 12:25:04 minos FaxGetty[3790]: MODEM set baud rate: 19200 baud, input flow XON/XOFF, output flow XON/XOFF
Oct 14 12:25:04 minos FaxGetty[3790]: MODEM flush i/o
Oct 14 12:25:04 minos FaxGetty[3790]: <-- [4:ATZ\r]
Oct 14 12:25:34 minos FaxGetty[3790]: MODEM TIMEOUT: reading line from modem
```

Here is a config for modem:

```
ModemType:              Class1          # use class 1 interface
ModemRate:              19200           # rate for DCE-DTE communication
ModemFlowControl:       xonxoff         # software flow control
#
ModemSetupDTRCmd:       ATS13=1&D2      # setup so DTR drop resets modem
ModemSetupDCDCmd:       AT&C1           # setup so DCD reflects carrier (or not)
ModemNoFlowCmd:         AT&H0&I0&R1     # setup modem for no flow control
ModemHardFlowCmd:       AT&H1&I0&R2     # setup modem for hardware flow control
ModemSoftFlowCmd:       AT&H2&I2&R1     # setup modem for software flow control
ModemResultCodesCmd:    ATQ0X4          # enable result codes
#
ModemMfrQueryCmd:       !USR
ModemModelQueryCmd:     ATI3
ModemRevQueryCmd:       ATI7            # XXX returns a multi-line result
#
# When AT+FCLASS=1 is issued the modem automatically switches
# to software flow control; these parameters let the fax software
# reset flow control as needed after entering Class 1.
#
Class1NFLOCmd:          AT&H0&I0&R1     # setup modem for no flow control
Class1HFLOCmd:          AT&H1&I0&R2     # setup modem for hardware flow control
Class1SFLOCmd:          ""              # modem does this automatically

#
# This should resolve "DIS/DTC received 3 times" errors:
#
Class1ResponseWaitCmd:  AT+FRS=1        # wait after sending TCF for response
#
# The remainder of this configuration is included so that the
# modem "idles" in Class 0 while not sending or receiving facsimile.
#
ModemSetupAACmd:        AT+FCLASS=0     # leave modem idling in class 0
ModemAnswerCmd:         AT+FCLASS=1A    # answer in Class 1
#
# When using AT+FRS=n we see USR modems reset themselves in the middle of sessions
# this is not good.  So, we seem to work-around that problem by not using the
# command.  Unfortunately, this isn't an ideal thing.
#
Class1SwitchingCmd:     "<delay\0727>"

#
## AvantFAX
#
FaxRcvdCmd:     bin/faxrcvd.php
DynamicConfig:  bin/dynconf.php
UseJobTSI:      true
```

We also tried to replace Sportster with ZyXEL U1496 (which was also working before this issue) and this one is also not responding. After connecting to modem with cu or minicom it appears connected but not response after AT+FCLASS? command or else. Could it be something in hylafax or am I missing something. I have browsed a lot of forums and after reboot of modem everything should work but in our case it is not like that.

**Update**

Ok now we are 100% sure modem is all right. We have tried to plug modem into win XP machine and also to different linux machine. On both modem is working without problem and I can query it with basi AT commands. It seems problem is with serial on first server but there is nothing in logs which could indicate problem. By the server is new HP 360e Gen8 ProLiant so I hope port has not died. I can connect to modem with cu -l /dev/ttyS0 but no AT commands are not working. I have also tried /etc/init.d/setserial restart but it does not help. System is Debian Wheezy 7.6 kernel 3.2.0-4-amd64

Thx very much for your help.

Comment: Defective serial port?

Comment: Yes it seems so, because we had tried to plug in the modem into another machine (windows XP with serial port) and I could access modem without problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK finally we have figured out where the problem was. HP Proliant DL360e Gen8 we are using has ilo4 connected to serial port and through this connection it allows remotely connect to console. After disabling ilo4 virtual serial port in ilo4 bios (Settings -> Serial CLI Status -> Disabled) everything start to work without problem.

Thx for your time